# How can I prevent the “User Agent” header of a WKWebView from changing?

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, nsurl, wkwebview

```
    let url =  NSURL(string:"http://www.examplepage.com/“)
            let Request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)


            Request.setValue("Custom-Agent", forHTTPHeaderField: "User-Agent")

            let task1 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(Request){ data, response, error in

                let contentPage =  NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                self.webView!.loadHTMLString(contentPage! as String, baseURL: url)

            }
            task1.resume()
```

I’ve used the following code to set the “User Agent” header of a WKWebView.

It works well when the app first loaded, but only after a button is clicked into the link the “User-Agent” changes.

How can I prevent the "User-Agent" from changing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For iOS 9, use the customUserAgent property on the web view.
2. For iOS 8 and earlier, do this instead:

   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent" : "BlahBlahBlah"])

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it. Here is the solution!

The ViewController:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://www.examplepage.com/")!
        webView!.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
        webView!.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true     
    }
```

The AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": “YourUserAgent”])

    return true
    }
```